# Where can I find a good Jquery Scrollbar tutorial?

Tags: jquery, scrollbar

Is out there a good tutorial about building a scrollbar with jquery?
Googling it, I have found only links to plugins, but nothing about building it myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**jScrollPane**](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) is a cross-browser jQuery plugin by Kelvin Luck which converts a browser's default scrollbars (on elements with a relevant overflow property) into an HTML structure which can be easily skinned with CSS.

[**SEE AN EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/XbjAe/)

Answer (score 1):

Not so much a tutorial but a pretty good plugin. It just replaces the scrollbars with custom ones.

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/